# TensorRT 3 Python API: add_concatenation

Tags: python, swig, tensorrt

I was trying to use TensorRT Python API to convert a model. An error occured while defining a concatenation layer, the code is:

```
concatLayer = network.add_concatenation([conv1.get_output(0),conv2.get_output(0)],2)
```

The error info is:

```
TypeError: in method 'NetworkDefinition_add_concatenation', argument 2 of type 'nvinfer1::ITensor *const *'
```

'`conv1.get_output(0)`' will return an `ITensor*` variable, how should I convert it to the type of `ITensor *const*` ?

Seems that the TensorRT python API was wrapped from its C++ version with SWIG, the API reference of add_concatenation() is:

> addConcatenation(ITensor *const *inputs, int nbInputs)=0 ->
>   IConcatenationLayer *
>
> add a concatenation layer to the network Parameters:
>
> ```
> inputs (*) – the input tensors to the layer
> nbInputs (*) – the number of input tensors
> also (See) –
> ```
>
> Returns:
>
> ```
> the new concatenation layer, or null if it could not be created
> **Warning** (All tensors must have the same dimensions for all dimensions except for channel.)
> ```